# How to get schema id from Schema registry? (using @KafkaListener)

Tags: avro, spring-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

[image]

I am consuming Kafka data using Spring Kafka @KafkaListener annotation and receiving objects of ConsumerRecord. Is there any way by which I can get the schema id that comes with raw Avro data (highlighted in the image attached)?

Comment: Why extract the schema ID from the message yourself? [KafkaAvroDeserializer](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/serdes-avro.html#avro-deserializer) already does it while deserializing Confluent-formatted messages.

Comment: I have four different processing logic based on the version of the schema. I wanted to map these processors to the schema id we get from the schema registry.

Comment: any luck finding an answer?